# Is their any reference in buddhism about time travell and parallel universe travell?

Tags: mind

As i've seen in hindhism their are lot of written things in hindu scriptures that a person or gods used to travel in different universes and time. But is their any mention of such powers in buddhism also? Where it is mentioned that a meditator has traveled time and to different worlds?
Is this possible to do this two things physically or its just mentally possible?

Answer (score 2):

One Sutta which such reference occur is [Rohitassa Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/7.2-Rohitassa-S-s2.26-piya.pdf).

> **Rohitassa’s astral journey**
>
> Once in the past, venerable sir, I was a seer named Rohitassa Bhoja,putta [son of Bhoja], possessed
>   of spiritual power, able to travel through the sky [space].  My speed was such, venerable sir, that I
>   could move just as fast as an archer with a strong bow,
>   trained, skillful, well-practised, experienced,
>   could easily shoot past the shadow of a palmyra tree with a light arrow.
>
> My stride was such, venerable sir, that it spanned the eastern ocean and the western ocean.
>   Then, venerable sir, the wish arose in me, ‘I will reach the end of the world by going.’
>
> Possessing such speed and such a stride, and having a lifespan of a hundred years, without pausing
>   except to eat, drink, take meals and snacks, to void and pee, to sleep and dispel tiredness. Yet I died
>   along the way without reaching the end of the world.
>
> It is wonderful, venerable sir! It is amazing, venerable sir! How well this was stated by the
>   Blessed One: ‘As to that end of the world, friend, where one is not born, does not age, does not die, does
>   not pass away, does not arise—it cannot be known, seen or reached by going, I say.’”

Moral story of this is that space travel is not a way to find a way out of [unsatisfactoriness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dukkha) and you would be dead before you real such goal through space exploration.

Also such references are found in the Abhidhamma. More on this see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/13087/295) and [others](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/search?q=parallel%20universe%20user%3A295).

Comment: is this only possible through conciousness or the person can do it physically also?

Comment: I think both physically and through consciousness. Also related: [abhiññā](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B9%9Addhi) and [iddhi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E1%B9%9Addhi}