# Suppose World War 3 occurs and manages to wipe out all humans and animals. Is the cycle of death and rebirth broken?

Tags: lay-buddhism, tibetan-buddhism

Or will human beings be magically reborn again in order to continue their journey to Nirvana?

Comment: Your questions includes "magically", which appears to be the basis of beliefs. In most religion, "Believing" is just trusting, without substantial evidence. Most evidences there are often just anecdotes, but we must realize the human mind is susceptible to filter disconfirming data out & even to illusionate. There is no real evidence to believe literal rebirth & afaik, the Buddha suggested not to blindly believe, but to question & see whether it's for your long term welfare.

Answer (score 1):

'Humans' are people who have a moral conscience & are humane.

'Animals' are people driven by instinct (such as survivalism, tribalism & terroritalism), emotion, without reflective wisdom.

'Human' & 'animal' are states of mind rather than physical qualities.

For example, the 'human state' is described as follows:

> *Sooner, I say, would that blind turtle, coming to the surface once every hundred years, insert its neck into that yoke with a single hole than the fool who has gone once to the nether world would regain the **human state**. For what reason? Because here, bhikkhus, there is no **conduct guided by the Dhamma**, no **righteous conduct**, no **wholesome activity**, no **meritorious activity**. Here there prevails mutual devouring, the devouring of the weak. For what reason? Because, bhikkhus, they have not **seen the Four Noble Truths**. What four? The noble truth of suffering … the noble truth of the way leading to the cessation of suffering.*
>
> *SN 56.47*

AN 6.39 says:

> *Bhikkhus, a god, a human or any other good state would not be evident from actions born of greed, hate and delusion. Yet, bhikkhus, from actions born of greed, hate and delusion a hellish being, an animal birth a ghostly birth or some other bad state would be evident.*
>
> *AN 6.39*

As for Nirvana, the suttas described it as the here-&-now end of greed, hatred & delusion. There is no 'journey' to 'Nirvana'. To 'journey' is to 'wander & roam'. '*Wandering & roaming*' is called '*samsara*'. '*Nirvana*' is found in the present. '*Samsara*' is not '*Nirvana*' and '*Nirvana*' is not '*samara*'.

Answer (score 1):

In Buddhism, there are 31 planes of existence ([“The Thirty-One Planes of Existence” by Venerable. Bhante Suvanno Mahathera](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/allexistence.pdf)) which make a universe. There are such infinite universes. (Page 27, [Abhidharma Pradeepika, volume 1](http://www.aathaapi.net/EBooks/AbhidhammatthaPradeepikaHQ1.pdf) by Mr. Amaradasa Rathanapala)

Also, there are multiple humanoid planets.

If the world gets destroyed then everyone is born somewhere else, either in a different humanoid planet in the same of a different universe, a different plane in the same of a different universe, or inter-dimensional hell which belong to any universe. The cycle will not be broken.

Also, see [Buddhist cosmology of the Theravada school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_cosmology_of_the_Theravada_school).

Comment: What if another war ended all human and animal lives in all planes of existence?

Comment: There is no war powerful enough to wipe 1000s of planets in a single universe let alone any parallel universes.

Comment: Also, this answer might be of interest: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/13087/295

Comment: How would you know if there is no such war capable of such destruction?

Comment: It's simple math, if you toss 1,000 coins and hoping for the odds that all 1,000 of them show heads, it'd be exceedingly exceedingly low, though not completely zero. Similarly, with countless number of planets in an infinite universe, the odds that every single human planet have a totally completely catastrophic war that wipes out all life would be infinitely infinitely low, though technically not at zero. That's why Samsara was, is, and will be going on forever.

Answer (score 0):

From [SN 15.3](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn15/sn15.003.than.html):

> "**From an inconstruable beginning comes transmigration. A
>   beginning point is not evident**, though beings hindered by ignorance
>   and fettered by craving are transmigrating & wandering on. Long have
>   you thus experienced stress, experienced pain, experienced loss,
>   swelling the cemeteries — enough to become disenchanted with all
>   fabricated things, enough to become dispassionate, enough to be
>   released."

From [MN 9](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.009.than.html):

> From the origination of [fermentation](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9414/471) comes the origination of
>   [ignorance](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8556/471). From the cessation of fermentation comes the cessation of
>   ignorance. .....
>
> From the origination of ignorance comes the origination of
>   fermentation. From the cessation of ignorance comes the cessation of
>   fermentation.

From [DN 15](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/dn/dn.15.0.than.html):

> "Thus, Ananda, **from name-and-form as a requisite condition comes
>   consciousness. From consciousness as a requisite condition comes
>   name-and-form.** From name-and-form as a requisite condition comes
>   contact. From contact as a requisite condition comes feeling. From
>   feeling as a requisite condition comes craving. From craving as a
>   requisite condition comes clinging. From clinging as a requisite
>   condition comes becoming. From becoming as a requisite condition comes
>   birth. From birth as a requisite condition, aging, death, sorrow,
>   lamentation, pain, distress, and despair come into play. Such is the
>   origination of this entire mass of stress.

As you can see above, the Buddha says that a beginning point for samsara is not seen.

There are also cyclic relationships like between [ignorance](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/8556/471) and fermentation (or [effluents](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9414/471)), and also between consciousness and name-and-form.

This is like the case of chicken and egg - which came first? A beginning point is not evident.

Answer (score 0):

Whoa! Really, if there is a particular set of cause& conditions  capable of doing such thing then the same would again make it because `Energy remains preserved`.

We are not merely body, rather a particular set of causes&conditions known as subcouncious mind state(citta).

2 cases arise::

1.)  Every citta is being wiped out.

2.) Citta is preserved.

1st one only possible when everyone attains `Nibbana`, which is not destruction.
If 2nd one occurs then just like life generated out of chemicals on earth(which came into existence through sun), same way it would generate again.

It seems that by thinking such amount of mass destruction, there is a lack of love, compassion in your life. So,

May you be free from this `evil idea` of wiping-out every life from everywhere.
Along with this, metta in song form too, let me love you(bieber).

Comment: Does this mean that all karmic life is back at square one on this game of snakes and ladders? Maybe we all need a second chance after all. Rest assured that World War 3 ended with a decisive victory for the living late last year.

Comment: No, preserved cittas will continue journey in (name-form)less realms. Rest assured @SinglemindedCompass , not just 2nd rather infinite chances are there till *citta* is being wiped-out. Yes, still recent even b/w usa & iran increased heart-beats.

Comment: I’m just working with the logical conclusions of canonical theories. WW3 ended with the word “gaslighting”. If you can analyse, you will see forces everywhere coming together that were at odds once.

Comment: Be happy-- do as you wish. Stay enthusiastic-- hope is must. You have come a long way in motivating self and others through songs. And @SinglemindedCompass, Last comment:: Namo Buddhaya.

Answer (score 0):

> 10. ‘There comes a time, Vasettha, when, sooner or later after a long period, this world contracts. At a time of contraction, beings are mostly born in the Abhassara Brahma world. And there they dwell, mind-made, feeding on delight, self-luminous, moving through the air, glorious — and they stay like that for a very long time.  (Aggana Sutta)

If a fantastic war occured, such that would make the world  unfit for human and animal life; nothing special would happen and beings would be in the unaffected realms.