# Why did we first incarnate?

Tags: birth

Our Number of births going into the past has to necasserily be finite not infinite.an infinite number of births without a first is logically infathomable.so why did we first incarnate?

Comment: just go with 'ignorance'... also, if we're talking about the desire realm, i guess something to do with hunger

Answer (score 2):

Most suttas in [SN 15](https://suttacentral.net/sn15) like [SN 15.1](https://suttacentral.net/sn15.1/en/sujato), have the following ending:

> Transmigration has no known beginning. No first point is found of
> sentient beings roaming and transmigrating, hindered by ignorance and
> fettered by craving. For such a long time you have undergone
> suffering, agony, and disaster, swelling the cemeteries. This is quite
> enough for you to become disillusioned, dispassionate, and freed
> regarding all conditions.”

From a different translation of the [Tears Sutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn15/sn15.003.than.html):

> From an inconstruable beginning comes transmigration. A beginning
> point is not evident, though beings hindered by ignorance and fettered
> by craving are transmigrating & wandering on. Long have you thus
> experienced stress, experienced pain, experienced loss, swelling the
> cemeteries — enough to become disenchanted with all fabricated things,
> enough to become dispassionate, enough to be released."

Please also see [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/34116/471).

Comment: I would agree and suggest further that the answer also relates strongly to some of the answers to the Unanswerable Questions which are presented as "unwise reflection" into the eternal/finite existence of the self.

Answer (score 1):

In the ultimate Truth there's no birth, past , present and future. birth is illusion.
That is why the Buddha said there is no apparent beginning. As there's no beginning for the rat horn or a sky flowers.

Answer (score 0):

In commentary, we born by avijjā. Avijjā arises by Kāmāsava, Bhavāsava, and Avijāsava. These 3 Āsavā originate Avijjā. It's non stop loop.

I can see only stronger and stronger unwholesome in the loop. And I don't think we can find the beginning.

Ignorant > Old and Death > Doing (Managing) > Old and Death > Nāma Rūpa Arise > Old and Death > Senses Arise > Old and Death > Meeting > Old and Death > Feeling > Old and Death > Remembering > Old and Death > Managing > Old and Death > Craving > Old and Death > Craving again and again > Old and Death > Doing (Managing) for New  Nāma Rūpa Arise as in Memory > Old and Death > Born as Managed > Old and Death > Arising Old and Death >  Arising Old and Death >  Arising Old and Death > Unlimited.